# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of null, removing element from array javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an element from an array when the onClick on the remove button is called, when the button is clicked I am getting **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null**

Why am I getting this error?

```
removeData(key) {
  console.log(key);
  const data = this.state.data;
  data[key] = null;
  this.setState({ data });
}

renderData(key){
    const user = this.props.data[key];
    console.log(user.name);
    console.log(user.id);
    return(
      <div key={key}>
          <li>  <strong> Name: </strong>  {user.name},
          <strong>  ID: </strong> {user.id} </li>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.removeData(key)}> Remove </button>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: what is this ?...

Comment: Right now your code is failing on your `console.log('user.name);`. So something is wrong with your `this.props.data[key]` which none of us could really be able to tell what it is.

Comment: implies that `user` is null in `{user.name}`

Comment: @cpugourou - looks like `react`

Answer (score 2):

> Why am I getting this error?

You are explicitly setting `data[key]` to `null`:

```
data[key] = null;
```

When the component rerenders it presumably calls `renderData` with the key that was "removed" (because the property is still there, its value is just `null`). `user` will be `null` and accessing `null.name` throws an error.

---

Depending on what you actually want, either skip `null` values in your `renderData` method, or actually *delete* the entry with

```
delete data[key];
```

Assigning `null` does *not* delete a property:

```js
var obj = {foo: 42};

// Doesn't actually remove the property
obj.foo = null;
console.log(obj);

// This removes the property
delete obj.foo;
console.log(obj);
```

> I am trying to remove an element from an array

If you really have an *array*, then there more things wrong. `{...this.state.data}` is not an appropriate way to clone an *array* because you end up with an *object*.

To properly perform this action on an array you would do

```
removeData(key) {
  // Assuming `key` is the index of the element
  // Create copy
  const data = Array.from(this.state.data);
  // Remove element at index `key`
  data.splice(key, 1);
  this.setState({ data });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
renderData(key){
    const user = this.props.data[key] || {}; // change
    console.log(user.name);
    console.log(user.id);
    return(
      <div key={key}>
          <li>  <strong> Name: </strong>  {user.name},
          <strong>  ID: </strong> {user.id} </li>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.removeData(key)}> Remove </button>
      </div>
    )
```

It seems like your data isn't ready when the component renders, so putting in a blank object will allow the component to render empty while the data loads.

edit: You could consider:

```
renderData(key){
        if (!this.props.data[key]) return null; //change
        const user = this.props.data[key];
        console.log(user.name);
        console.log(user.id);
        return(
          <div key={key}>
              <li>  <strong> Name: </strong>  {user.name},
              <strong>  ID: </strong> {user.id} </li>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.removeData(key)}> Remove </button>
          </div>
        )
```

This would hide the component as the data is being fetched.  It's up to you then to communicate that the data is loading to the user.  You could pass down a `loading` prop that is set to true when the request is fired and set to false when the request returns data and show either some loading text or an animation.

Comment: Okay, now it removes the correct element for a split second but the remove button is still there, also after that split second the entire page refreshes. Why is the page refreshing?

Comment: @Omar: If the button is inside a form then the form will be submitted when the button is clicked. Buttons are *submit buttons* by default. You can make the button act as a plain button by adding `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

### Removing objects from arrays

A good way to remove objects from arrays is to use filter. Using filter keeps us safe from bugs that come from using the index inside of the map function. `data.map((item,index) => <div key={index} onClick={this.removeData(index)}> {item.fruit} </div>)`. This can cause serious problems when removing objects from the array.

What react says about this.

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may
>   change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
>   with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an
>   in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a
>   key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then
>   React will default to using indexes as keys.

### The Filter Approach

This approach takes whatever id the object has and returns every object that has a different id.

`this.setState({ data: temp.filter(item => item.id !== id) });`

### Working Example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'; 
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
        this.state = { 
     data:[
     { fruit: "apple", id:1 },
     { fruit: "orange", id:2 }, 
     { fruit: "pineapple", id:3 },
    ],
    }
  }
      removeData = (id) => {
      const { data } = this.state;  
      const temp = data.slice();  
      this.setState({ data: temp.filter(item => item.id !== id) });
    }
    renderData = () =>{
        const { data } = this.state;
        return data.map((item) => {
         return  <div key={item.id}>
         <label> {item.fruit} </label>
         {item.id}
         <button onClick={() => this.removeData(item.id)}> Remove </button>
         </div>         
        })     
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderData()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```