# Uncaught TypeError: data.push is not a function. How can I get around this push error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First I have this addNameId method

```
addNameId(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = this.props.data;
  data.push({name:this.props.name, id: this.props.id})
  this.props.setData(data);

}
```

Everything is good until I call removeData

```
removeData(key) {
  console.log(key);
  const data = {...this.state.data};
  delete data[key];
  this.setState({ data });
}
```

Once I call removeData I can no longer add anything to data.

this is where I call them

```
  renderData(key){
          if (!this.props.data[key]) return null;
          const user = this.props.data[key] || {};
          console.log(user.name);
          console.log(user.id);
          return(
            <div key={key}>
                <li>  <strong> Name: </strong>  {user.name},
                <strong>  ID: </strong> {user.id} </li>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.removeData(key)}> Remove </button>
            </div>
          )
        }
```

What can I replace   `data.push({name:this.props.name, id: this.props.id})` with?

Edit:

My constructor

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.setId = this.setId.bind(this);
    this.setName = this.setName.bind(this);
    this.setData = this.setData.bind(this);
    this.removeData = this.removeData.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      data: [],
      id: '',
    };
  }
```

Comment: is `this.props.data` an Array? if not, that's why you can't push to it

Comment: Do you have a constructor where you initialize the state of this component? If so, can you add that code to your post?

Comment: if it has no `push` method it's not an `Array` (not sure what you mean by object array ... an array whose items are objects? that would be an Array and should have a `push` method)

Comment: You should have read the answer I gave to previews question (especially the last part): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147607/218196 *"If you really have an array, then there more things wrong. `{...this.state.data}` is not an appropriate way to clone an array because you end up with an object."*

Comment: added constructor code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a re few things that you need to correct.

1. In the `addNameId` function you specify `var data = this.props.data;`, however only set a reference of `data` to the prop and so you are mutating the props directly

Change to

```
addNameId(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = [..this.props.data];
  data.push({name:this.props.name, id: this.props.id})
  this.props.setData(data);

}
```

2. You are creating a new oobject from `this.state.data` in `removeData`, by `const data = {...this.state.data};`. What it does is that it destructures the contents within `this.state.data` and creates an object instead. Since `this.state.data` was an array, you should have done `const data = [...this.state.data];`
3. delete removes a key form an object and when you use an array, you can use `splice` to remove object at an `index` equal to `key` like `data.splice(key, 1)`

Change the function to

```
removeData(key) {
  console.log(key);
  const data = [...this.state.data];
  data.splice(key, 1);
  this.setState({ data });
}
```

Comment: `data.splice(key,1);` does not work the page completely refreshes when removeData is called. I replaced it with `delete data[key];` and this removes the name and id from the object, I had to add `if (!this.props.data[key]) return null;` in renderData because the page kept the "Name:, ID:" and remove button on the screen. How can I completely remove the objects that are null from data so they do not take up a slot.

Comment: Is key, the index of the object in the data array

Comment: I messed up, I should not use delete I need to use splice, but like I said splice is not working. Yes key is the index of the object in the data array.